# How is the NRR (net run rate) in IPL calculated

Tags: cricket, indian-premier-league

I am having a confusion regarding the net run rate calculation in IPL. The thing is after all the 14 matches, the NRR of KKR was +0.587 with 14 points. And after 13 matches, the NRR of MI was -0.048 with 12 points (in IPL, a team gets 2 points for each victory). Today was the last match of MI. If they were to qualify for the playoffs, they had to win with such a big margin so that their NRR surpasses the NRR of KKR. Now I read in a newspaper that if MI bats first and wins with a margin of 171 runs or more, their NRR will be more than KKR’s. It was also written that if MI bats second, it is impossible for them to make their NRR more than KKR’s no matter how large the winning margin is. I didn’t understand why this makes sense. I know NRR is basically the average of the difference of runs scored and runs conceded. So for instance, assume MI bowled first, wrapped SRH up for just 20 runs, and then chased the 20 runs in 1 over. So in that case, the NRR of MI for this match should be (20-1)=19. So their NRR for the season should become roughly 19/14>1. So in this case, they should qualify for the playoffs. What exactly am I missing?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of what is our "canonical" NRR question; the issue is that NRR is _not_ "the average of the difference of runs scored and runs conceded", it is "the difference of the average rate of runs scored and the average rate of runs conceded". Mathematically, this works out differently.

Comment: For a worked example of how a team batting second rules themselves out, see [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/22730/cricket-world-cup-2019-qualifying-semi-final). The numbers are different but the same principle applies.